# Animate subview on UIViewController view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8

I have UITableView as a subview over UIView (parent view) of UIViewController. When i'm animating my parent view as below:

```
       UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
            viewController?.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,568)
        }, completion: {_ in

        })
```

I observed that my subview (table view) is not animating. I tried setting Autoresizing Mask of subviews to flexibleWidth and flexibleHeight, but din't get any success. Anybody having any idea why its happening.

Comment: are you using auto layout? setting the frame has no effect if you do!

Comment: Yes! I'm using Autolayout but right now my table view covering the complete screen with leading, trailing, top, bottom constraints constant value set to "0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using auto layout (which is the default in iOS 8/9 on Xcode 6/7) you need to change the constraints of your view inside he `UIView` animation closure, instead of changing the frame.

If you are not using auto layout, then you can update the frame as above, however, I'd imagine you are. Thus you need to call `layoutSubviews`, then programatically set new constraints that represent your desired change to the layout, and finally call `layoutSubviews` again, inside the animation closure.

Example:

```
func AnimateBackgroundHeight() {
    self.view.layoutSubviews()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
         self.heightCon.constant = 600 // heightCon is the IBOutlet to the constraint
         self.view.layoutSubviews()    
    })
}
```

Comment: Yes! I'm using Autolayout but right now my table view covering the complete screen with leading, trailing, top, bottom constraints constant value set to "0"

Comment: Sure, then use the example I show above. You need to change constraints on the view, NOT the frame